# How are wheels semantically related to knees, as "rodilla" (knees) is said to come from Latin's "rota" (wheel)?

Tags: etimología, cuerpo-humano

I was reading the entry [*poples*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poples) in Wiktionary:

> From [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) [*kʷekʷlóm](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7ek%CA%B7l%C3%B3m), [*kʷékʷlos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7%C3%A9k%CA%B7los), [*kʷékʷléh](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7%C3%A9k%CA%B7l%C3%A9h%E2%82%82)₂. Cognates include [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) [*wheel*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wheel#English), [Ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek) [*κύκλος*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%8D%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (kúklos, “wheel”) and [Tocharian B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tocharian_languages) [*kokale*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kokale#Tocharian_B) (“cart, wagon”). **For the semantic shift compare [Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language) [*rodilla*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rodilla#Spanish) (“knee”) from [roda](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roda#Spanish) (“wheel”)**.

[RAE - ASALE](https://dle.rae.es/rodilla) affirms the last sentence above.

> **rodilla**
> Del lat. tardío *rotella* 'ruedecita', dim. de *rota* 'rueda'.

Can someone please elaborate "the semantic shift" behind *rodilla* and *roda*? What notions do they share semantically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main theories for this. The simplest one is the round shape of the knee, possibly influenced by the name of the knee bone, the *[rótula](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%B3tula)*. Dicciomed, among others, [claims this to be the reason](https://dicciomed.usal.es/palabra/rodilla):

> Lat. alto mediev. *rotella*(m) es 'ruedecilla' pero también 'rótula'; en castellano por metonimia de la parte por el todo pasó a significar 'rodilla' y está documentado *rodiella* en 1236; *rodilla* desplazó a *hinojo* de lat. *geniculu*(m), diminutivo de *genu*, el término lat. de 'rodilla'.

But looking in the *[Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española](http://ntlle.rae.es)* (NTLLE), we find another theory in 1611, by Francisco del Rosal in his "*Origen y etymología de todos los vocablos originales de la Lengua Castellana*":

> **Rodilla,** ò por la forma redonda, ò porque trahían antiguamente en las capas ò manteos una *Ruedilla*, que oy dicen *Rosca*, para arrodillarse en las Iglesias; [...]; y otros la trahían pegada a la misma rodilla, de donde se le pegó el nombre.

(Note that this is old Spanish and has somewhat different spelling). According to this theory, the name *rodilla* comes from a donut-shaped device that was used in old times to put under the knees when kneeling in churches. This device was round and called *ruedilla*, and may have given its name to *rodilla*. This theory does not seem to appear in any more recent dictionaries, so the general consensus seems to be the other one. It is, in any case, interesting.

Answer (score 4):

If you search Google with the terms "knee movement axis", you can get a lot of scientific articles describing how a knee "works". In them you can find the word "rotation" because the knee **rotates**.

Let me quote a random one from the [US National Library of Medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4454551/):

> Later studies have suggested that the knee motion can be better
> described as simultaneous **rotation** about two fixed axes: the
> flexion-extension axis (FEA) in the posterior femoral condyles and the
> longitudinal axis (LRA) in the tibia

Something able to rotate is a **rota** (wheel), a little rota is a **rotella**, and from rotella we have got **rótula** and **rodilla** (knee) in Spanish.

I'm no etimology expert, I just wanted to point you the relation between wheel and rodilla.